# How do I build a devoted cleric with the WotC builder?

Tags: dnd-4e, cleric, dnd-4e-character-builder

I'm trying to build a new character using the [Wizards of the Coast character builder](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/tool.aspx?x=dnd/4new/tool/characterbuilder) — a *devoted cleric*. I've previously built a warpriest cleric with no trouble, but devoted cleric is simply not listed as a character class in the custom build. This seems strange since it's listed on p61 of the *Player's Handbook* as a possible build, right next to battle cleric.

Is it possible to create a devoted cleric using the WotC character builder or not?  Should I start with a warpriest or templar cleric and change feats, powers and abilities as per the player's manual suggestions, or will I miss out on essential powers that a devoted cleric should have? Or does the devoted cleric class go by some other name in the character builder?

Comment: I believe devoted is a build of templar, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templar and Warpriest are two separate classes that both fall under the "Cleric" name and they each have their own builds that are associated with them.

Devoted Cleric is a build option of Templar cleric so to build one on DDI you will need to build a Templar and pick the Devoted Cleric build option/class features.

To build a Devoted cleric do the following:

- Open DDI
- Create a 'Custom' character
- Choose Cleric (Templar) as your class
- Choose the Devoted Cleric build option.

As far as build options are typically just ideas, sometimes they have specific class features that are selected along with them and that will dictate some of your mechanics. That is no the case here with this cleric. Other times the build option you select opens up some feat choices that is not the case here (no powers are restricted to Devoted Clerics only). This is consistent with most of the rest of clericdom in that your powers and abilities are more dependent on your deity than your build.

Comment: It's worth noting that the "build options" are nothing more than preset combinations of options you can set and reset manually; the OP is concerned that he has to use the build option explicitly or he'll miss out on certain features, and it would be nice to assuage his fears on that note.

Comment: @BESW - Yes, that was actually a concern too. I didn't realise until just now that the DDI character builder includes many of the appropriate *common* powers without listing them on the selection panes. You only see them when you look at your character sheet in full (or re-select your domain in the case of the cleric). In this case, I thought I'd somehow picked a cleric build that had no channel divinity powers!

Comment: @detly yes, anything you get for free on your class/build will not be listed anywhere but on the sheet. (that's not quite true, but effectively so, it's in the class listing when you select your class, but that's highly obscure and it's often not clear what you've picked)

Comment: @BESW - I think you're wrong on this. If you don't select a build on the CB, you can't select feats and powers.

Comment: @detly Granted, I haven't used the CB myself for a few months, but specific build selection never limited options in my experience--choosing class, race, and class features might limit feat options, but "builds" are just suggested groupings of class features and powers. If you [come into chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) I'm sure we can rustle up some people with more up-to-date experience.